# Why does it not work by changing anything in the code on the expo go app but on the physical Android device it doesn't work?

Tags: android, react-native, expo, expo-go

Let me explain better, I created an app with react that reads QR codes, I did various tests and I always used expo go and it always worked (at the first try).
now I imported it onto my device using "eas build -p android --profile preview" and when I install it the application opens and shows me the camera but if I frame the QR CODE nothing works it doesn't perform any actions.

So I wonder how is this possible? please can you help me? I'll leave you the code below.
From expo go it doesn't report errors to me precisely because the app works if I wanted to see the logs on my physical Android device I can't so I don't know if there are other problems.

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, Button, Text, Alert } from 'react-native';
import { Camera } from 'expo-camera';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'column',
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
  },
  preview: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  scanText: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
    color: 'red', // Colore rosso per il testo di errore
  },
  qrFrame: {
    width: 150,
    height: 150,
    borderRadius: 10,
    borderColor: '#FFF',
    borderWidth: 2,
    position: 'absolute',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  qrCodeText: {
    fontSize: 16,
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#FFF',
  },
});

export default function App() {
  const [hasCameraPermission, setHasCameraPermission] = useState(null);
  const [scanned, setScanned] = useState(false);
  const [scannedData, setScannedData] = useState('');
  const [serverResponse, setServerResponse] = useState('');
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      try {
        const { status } = await Camera.requestCameraPermissionsAsync();
        if (status !== 'granted') {
          throw new Error('Camera permission denied');
        }
        setHasCameraPermission(true);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error while requesting camera permission:', error.message);
        setHasCameraPermission(false);
      }
    })();
  }, []);

  const handleBarCodeScanned = async ({ data }) => {
    console.log('Barcode scanned:', data);
    setScanned(true);
    setScannedData(`Dati: ${data}`);

    try {
      const response = await fetch('https://www.chesifastasera.com/handleQR.php', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          Accept: 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ qrData: data }),
      });

      console.log('Server response status:', response.status);

      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error(`HTTP Error! Code: ${response.status}`);
      }

      const responseData = await response.text();
      console.log('Server response data:', responseData);
      setServerResponse(responseData);

      // Altri passi basati sulla risposta del server qui

    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error during server request:', error.message);
      setError(error.message); // Imposta l'errore per visualizzarlo nell'app
    }
  };

  const resetScanner = () => {
    console.log('Resetting scanner...');
    setScanned(false);
    setScannedData('');
    setServerResponse('');
    setError(null); // Pulisce l'errore quando si riprova
  };

  if (hasCameraPermission === null) {
    console.log('Camera permission is still being checked...');
    return <View />;
  }

  if (hasCameraPermission === false) {
    console.log('Camera permission denied.');
    return <Text>Camera permission denied</Text>;
  }

  console.log('Rendering camera component...');
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Camera
        onBarCodeScanned={scanned ? undefined : handleBarCodeScanned}
        style={styles.preview}
      >
        <View style={styles.qrFrame}>
          <Text style={styles.qrCodeText}>{scannedData}</Text>
        </View>
      </Camera>
      {error && (
        <Text style={styles.scanText}>{`Errore: ${error}`}</Text>
      )}
      {scanned && !error && (
        <View>
          <Text style={styles.scanText}>{`Risposta del server: ${serverResponse}`}</Text>
          <Button title="Scansiona di nuovo" onPress={resetScanner} />
        </View>
      )}
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: The code you show seems completely unrelated to QR Code scanning?

Comment: Please see these two links for a solution. https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/4187 or https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/2426
I hope the link provided works for you.

Comment: you're right, sorry, I pasted another code and I didn't realize it, thanks in fact. I have updated with the correct QR CODE @GregFenton

Comment: thank you very much for the answer and for the 2 links you inserted, but what I mean is that the problem is inside my app which is used to scan QR CODES, if I use ExpoGo to do the tests it always works but if I install the app on my device (I tried different devices) and the app opens, it also shows me the camera but it doesn't seem to read the QR code or in reality it seems like it can't. to connect or send me a reply. What do you think? I even thought it was an internet problem but I don't know.@PratikPrakashBindage